# Ethereum - to implement multi wallet connect feature

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

In our application we would like to give a multi wallet connect feature with Ethereum network like using Meta-mask wallet, coin-Base-Wallet, wallet-Connect etc... there are some packages exist like web3Modal, web3-react etc.. but when I tried I think I am missing something and it doesn't work for me, can you please let us know any article or any codebase regarding this.. thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to go about connecting multiple wallets to Dapp](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91039/best-way-to-go-about-connecting-multiple-wallets-to-dapp)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, will check on it!

Comment: I tried and used @web3-onboard/core library ,it works but right after connected with desired wallet (ex.. coinbase) on top right side of the web page i am getting some tag contains wallet information and when click on that it drop down some additional information, but i don't want such information since we would like to show in our app with our design pattern, so how could i make it

Comment: Sounds like you are going to develop something of your own design.

Comment: You should state more clearly what features are you looking for and what issues did you have with existing libraries. There are options like https://wagmi.sh/ or https://github.com/family/connectkit.